# Find Child with Parent having specific information

Tags: sql-server, hierarchical-data

I am trying to find children whose parent have some specific information from different relational tables.
I have four tables as shown below

[image]

**Search Criteria** :  Get all the "Section" who has parent as "Inventory" level with attached User name containing 'a' letter and role id is 'employee' (Please see *LevelsUser* table for relation).

I tried CTE (common table expression') approach to find the correct Section level but here I have to pass level Id as hard coded value and I cannot search all Section in the table.

```
WITH LevelsTree AS 
(
   SELECT Id, ParentLevelId, Level
   FROM Levels 
   WHERE Level='Section'  // here i need to pass value
   UNION ALL

   SELECT ls.Id, ls.ParentLevelId, ls.Level
   FROM Levels ls
   JOIN LevelsTree lt ON ls.Id = lt.ParentLevelId
)

SELECT * FROM LevelsTree
```

I need to find all sections match the above criteria.
Please help me here.

Comment: CTEs are not available in mysql until version 8 is this question tagged correctly?

Comment: what is the `HierarchyPosition` table? It is now described in table schema.

Comment: just curious if you where able to use the query below with dynamic parent level name parameter? Where you able to feed @parentLevelName with proper value?

Answer (score 1):

For hierarchical checks you need to select from and then join to the same table `Levels`. So something like this should help you:

```
declare @parentLevelName varchar(20) = 'Inventory';

with cte as (
    select distinct 
        l1.id,
        l1.Level 
    from Levels l1
    join Levels l2 on l2.id=l1.ParentLevelId 
           and l2.Level = @parentLevelName -- use variable instead of hardcoded `Inventory`
    where l1.Level='Section' -- replace `Section` with @var containing your value
) select * from cte
join LevelUsers lu on lu.LevelId=cte.id
join Users u on u.Id = lu.UserId 
                and u.UserName like '%a%' -- this letter check is not efficient
join Role r on r.id=lu.RoleId and r.Role='employee'
```

Note, the above query selects data only from the 4 tables which you have described in DB schema. However, you original query contains a reference to the `HierarchyPosition` table which you haven't described. If you really need to include `HiearchyPosition` reference then specify how it relates to the other 4 tables.

Also note, condition `and u.UserName like '%a%'` used to satisfy your requirement of `User name containing 'a' letter` is not efficient because of the leading `%`, which prevents the use of indexes. Consider changing your requirements if possible to `User name starts with 'a' letter`. This way `and u.UserName like 'a%'` will allow the use of index over `Users` table if it exists.

HTH

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have put HierarchyPosition table by mistake which i have corrected in the post. Above query is not solving my problem but helps me to reach some work around. Thank you for your kind reply.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar if you add further details about the errors/issues you get we may try to further improve the query to meet your requirements.

Comment: as per above solution, i can find matching criteria for 'Inventory' but it is not the case always and it could be 'Store' or 'Functional Area' which is dynamically identified in one SQL query. so how to handle it?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar you just need to pass that value via variable. So instead of hardcoded `'Inventory'`, there should be a reference to a `varchar(20)` variable like `@parentLevelName`. Are you calling this piece from stored procedure or as a statement from code or just running it manually via SQL Server Management Studio? See the updated answer.